# How to upload and save a pickle file to a django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman, pickle

As it says in the title, I am trying to upload a model.pkl and save it in an API made in django.
I manage to save the model.pkl correctly in the API, however the file is uploaded in a corrupt way, because I cannot read the pickle file.

Im open to any solutions that can make the pickle file be uploaded, stored and readed in the API.

#### Class to upload the file and save it

```py
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def put(self, request):
        file = request.data.get('file', None)
        file_name = f'path/{file.name}'

        path = default_storage.save(name=file_name, content=ContentFile(file.read()))
        tmp_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)

        if file is not None:
            return Response(f'File: {file.name} successfully uploaded and saved!', status=HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(f'File not found!', status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

#### Error when reading the file

```py
def read_PickleModel(path_to_PickleModel):
    with open(path_to_PickleModel, 'rb') as f:
        pickle_model = pickle.load(f)
    return pickle_model

read_PickleModel(path_to_PickleModel)

Traceback:
DEBUG: An exception has ocurred: invalid load key, '-'.
```

#### Postman

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show how the original pickle generated, is it definitely not corrupted?

Comment: @IainShelvington defenitely is not corrupted, I tested before. It is corrupted when I uploaded and stored in the API

Comment: @IainShelvington when I read the pickle model in a colab notebook, it works without any problems. Also I tried with a different model.pkl and was the same case.

Comment: Can you show how you are sending/generating the pickle and the output of `print(file.content_type, file.charset)` in your view?

Comment: Here is the print: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------167993137263431154392844 utf-8

Comment: For how the pickle model was created I cant show all the process, but was saved normally  with `pickle.dump(data, f)`. Im 100% sure before uploading is not corrupted. Should I share the colab code?

Comment: You may have some issue in your code that uploads the file, the content type is corrupted/not valid. Please show that code

Comment: @IainShelvington I upload the file using POSTMAN, the class used is FileUploadView which is above, I will attach what I do in postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [FileUploadParser](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser) the entire body of the request should be the file contents, don't send the file as form data.

To do this in Postman, select "binary" as the data type instead of "form-data" and select your file there

[image]

To set the filename you need to set a header "Content-Disposition" and pass `attachment; filename=<your_filename.ext>`

[image]